# converting routing from state provider to route provider

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following code on my config.JS which works perfectly fine:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,
    $ocLazyLoadProvider, IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider,
    adalAuthenticationServiceProvider, $httpProvider) {

    // Configure Idle settings
    IdleProvider.idle(5); // in seconds
    IdleProvider.timeout(120); // in seconds

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboards/dashboard_1");

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        // Set to true if you want to see what and when is dynamically loaded
        debug: true
    });

    $stateProvider

        .state('dashboards', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/dashboards",
            templateUrl: "views/common/content.html",
        })
        .state('dashboards.dashboard_1', {
            url: "/dashboard_1",
            templateUrl: "views/dashboard_1.html",
            resolve: {
                loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        {

                            serie: true,
                            name: 'angular-flot',
                            files: [ 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js', 'js/plugins/flot/curvedLines.js', 'js/plugins/flot/angular-flot.js', ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'angles',
                            files: ['js/plugins/chartJs/angles.js', 'js/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js']
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'angular-peity',
                            files: ['js/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js', 'js/plugins/peity/angular-peity.js']
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            }
        })
```

When I try to convert  it to use the route provider like this:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,
    $ocLazyLoadProvider, IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider,
    adalAuthenticationServiceProvider, $httpProvider) {

    // Configure Idle settings
    IdleProvider.idle(5); // in seconds
    IdleProvider.timeout(120); // in seconds

    //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboards/dashboard_1");

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        // Set to true if you want to see what and when is dynamically loaded
        debug: true
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.when("/dashboard_1", {
        controller: "MainCtrl",
        templateUrl: "/views/dashboard_1.html",
        resolve: {
                        loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                {

                                    serie: true,
                                    name: 'angular-flot',
                                    files: [ 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js', 'js/plugins/flot/curvedLines.js', 'js/plugins/flot/angular-flot.js', ]
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'angles',
                                    files: ['js/plugins/chartJs/angles.js', 'js/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js']
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'angular-peity',
                                    files: ['js/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js', 'js/plugins/peity/angular-peity.js']
                                }
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
    }).otherwise({ redirectTo: "/dashboard_1" });
```

App.js

```
(function () {
    angular.module('inspinia', [
        'ui.router',                    // Routing
        'oc.lazyLoad',                  // ocLazyLoad
        'ui.bootstrap',                 // Ui Bootstrap
        'pascalprecht.translate',       // Angular Translate
        'ngIdle',                       // Idle timer
        'AdalAngular',                  // ADAL JS Angular
        'ngRoute'                       // Routing
    ])
})();
```

I get a blank page, with no errors on the console. I am stuck and without ideas where to look

http://screencast.com/t/caOYjmZxbGD

Comment: I think you meant to use [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) from `ngRoute`, not [`$urlRouterProvider`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider) from `ui.router`. Is that right?

Comment: yes I want to replace the uiprovider(states) by the most common one url routes

Comment: any idea how? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're using the wrong provider. See my first comment

Comment: please let us know the exact correction as I am new to angular syntax, its hard to spot this