# Angular JS App shows blank screen

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, adal

I have the following app configuration which should load one full page, however instead its showing nothing and when I check the console its totally empty with zero errors:

[image]

My code is as follows:

App.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('inspinia', ['ngRoute', 'AdalAngular'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when("/dashboard_1", {
        controller: "MainCtrl",
        templateUrl: "/views/dashboard_1.html",
        resolve: {
            loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                    {
                        serie: true,
                        name: 'angular-flot',
                        files: ['js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js', 'js/plugins/flot/curvedLines.js', 'js/plugins/flot/angular-flot.js', ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'angles',
                        files: ['js/plugins/chartJs/angles.js', 'js/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js']
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'angular-peity',
                        files: ['js/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js', 'js/plugins/peity/angular-peity.js']
                    }
                ]);
            }
        }
    }).otherwise({ redirectTo: "/dashboard_1" });


}]);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="inspinia">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Page title set in pageTitle directive -->
    <title page-title></title>

    <!-- Font awesome -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Main Inspinia CSS files -->
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link id="loadBefore" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  

</head>

<!-- ControllerAs syntax -->
<!-- Main controller with serveral data used in Inspinia theme on diferent view -->
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">

<!-- Main view  -->
<div ui-view></div>

<!-- jQuery and Bootstrap -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- MetsiMenu -->
<script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>

<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<!-- Peace JS -->
<script src="js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
<script src="js/inspinia.js"></script>

<!-- Main Angular scripts-->
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/angular-idle/angular-idle.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.0/js/adal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.0/js/adal-angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Anglar App Script -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!--<script src="js/config.js"></script>-->
<!--<script srjs/translations.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>-->
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Dashboard 1. html is a huge file that is not relevant to put here:
http://screencast.com/t/nDGUlMGn

and controllers.js has a MainCtrl

```
function MainCtrl() {

    /**
     * slideInterval - Interval for bootstrap Carousel, in milliseconds:
     */
    this.slideInterval = 5000;

    /**
     * states - Data used in Advanced Form view for Chosen plugin
     */
    this.states = [
        'Alabama',
        'Alaska',
        'Arizona',
        'Arkansas',
        'California',
        'Colorado',
        'Connecticut',
        'Delaware',
        'Florida',
        'Georgia',
        'Hawaii',
        'Idaho',
        'Illinois',
        'Indiana',
        'Iowa',
        'Kansas',
        'Kentucky',
        'Louisiana',
        'Maine',
        'Maryland',
        'Massachusetts',
        'Michigan',
        'Minnesota',
        'Mississippi',
        'Missouri',
        'Montana',
        'Nebraska',
        'Nevada',
        'New Hampshire',
        'New Jersey',
        'New Mexico',
        'New York',
        'North Carolina',
        'North Dakota',
        'Ohio',
        'Oklahoma',
        'Oregon',
        'Pennsylvania',
        'Rhode Island',
        'South Carolina',
        'South Dakota',
        'Tennessee',
        'Texas',
        'Utah',
        'Vermont',
        'Virginia',
        'Washington',
        'West Virginia',
        'Wisconsin',
        'Wyoming'
    ];

    /**
     * persons - Data used in Tables view for Data Tables plugin
     */
    this.persons = [
        {
            id: '1',
            firstName: 'Monica',
            lastName: 'Smith'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            firstName: 'Sandra',
            lastName: 'Jackson'
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Underwood'
        },
        {
            id: '4',
            firstName: 'Chris',
            lastName: 'Johnatan'
        },
        {
            id: '5',
            firstName: 'Kim',
            lastName: 'Rosowski'
        }
    ];

    /**
     * check's - Few variables for checkbox input used in iCheck plugin. Only for demo purpose
     */
    this.checkOne = true;
    this.checkTwo = true;
    this.checkThree = true;
    this.checkFour = true;

    /**
     * knobs - Few variables for knob plugin used in Advanced Plugins view
     */
    this.knobOne = 75;
    this.knobTwo = 25;
    this.knobThree = 50;

    /**
     * Variables used for Ui Elements view
     */
    this.bigTotalItems = 175;
    this.bigCurrentPage = 1;
    this.maxSize = 5;
    this.singleModel = 1;
    this.radioModel = 'Middle';
    this.checkModel = {
        left: false,
        middle: true,
        right: false
    };

    /**
     * groups - used for Collapse panels in Tabs and Panels view
     */
    this.groups = [
        {
            title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
            content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1'
        },
        {
            title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
            content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2'
        }
    ];

    /**
     * alerts - used for dynamic alerts in Notifications and Tooltips view
     */
    this.alerts = [
        { type: 'danger', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' },
        { type: 'success', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' },
        { type: 'info', msg: 'OK, You are done a great job man.' }
    ];

    /**
     * addAlert, closeAlert  - used to manage alerts in Notifications and Tooltips view
     */
    this.addAlert = function() {
        this.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!'});
    };

    this.closeAlert = function(index) {
        this.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    };

    /**
     * randomStacked - used for progress bar (stacked type) in Badges adn Labels view
     */
    this.randomStacked = function() {
        this.stacked = [];
        var types = ['success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger'];

        for (var i = 0, n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1); i < n; i++) {
            var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4));
            this.stacked.push({
                value: Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1),
                type: types[index]
            });
        }
    };
    /**
     * initial run for random stacked value
     */
    this.randomStacked();

    /**
     * summernoteText - used for Summernote plugin
     */
    this.summernoteText = ['<h3>Hello Jonathan! </h3>',
    '<p>dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <strong>Lorem Ipsum has been the dustrys</strong> standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more',
        'recently with</p>'].join('');

    /**
     * General variables for Peity Charts
     * used in many view so this is in Main controller
     */
    this.BarChart = {
        data: [5, 3, 9, 6, 5, 9, 7, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 3, 2, 7, 9, 6, 4, 5, 7, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 5, 6, 8, 3, 2, 1],
        options: {
            fill: ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7"],
            width: 100
        }
    };

    this.BarChart2 = {
        data: [5, 3, 9, 6, 5, 9, 7, 3, 5, 2],
        options: {
            fill: ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7"]
        }
    };

    this.BarChart3 = {
        data: [5, 3, 2, -1, -3, -2, 2, 3, 5, 2],
        options: {
            fill: ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7"]
        }
    };

    this.LineChart = {
        data: [5, 9, 7, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 9, 6, 5, 9, 4, 7, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5, 1, 2, 9, 5, 4, 7],
        options: {
            fill: '#1ab394',
            stroke: '#169c81',
            width: 64
        }
    };

    this.LineChart2 = {
        data: [3, 2, 9, 8, 47, 4, 5, 1, 2, 9, 5, 4, 7],
        options: {
            fill: '#1ab394',
            stroke: '#169c81',
            width: 64
        }
    };

    this.LineChart3 = {
        data: [5, 3, 2, -1, -3, -2, 2, 3, 5, 2],
        options: {
            fill: '#1ab394',
            stroke: '#169c81',
            width: 64
        }
    };

    this.LineChart4 = {
        data: [5, 3, 9, 6, 5, 9, 7, 3, 5, 2],
        options: {
            fill: '#1ab394',
            stroke: '#169c81',
            width: 64
        }
    };

    this.PieChart = {
        data: [1, 5],
        options: {
            fill: ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7"]
        }
    };

    this.PieChart2 = {
        data: [226, 360],
        options: {
            fill: ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7"]
        }
    };
    this.PieChart3 = {
        data: [0.52, 1.561],
        options: {
            fill: ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7"]
        }
    };
    this.PieChart4 = {
        data: [1, 4],
        options: {
            fill: ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7"]
        }
    };
    this.PieChart5 = {
        data: [226, 134],
        options: {
            fill: ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7"]
        }
    };
    this.PieChart6 = {
        data: [0.52, 1.041],
        options: {
            fill: ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7"]
        }
    };
};
```

this is content.html

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div ng-include="'views/common/navigation.html'"></div>

    <!-- Page wraper -->
    <!-- ng-class with current state name give you the ability to extended customization your view -->
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg {{$state.current.name}}">

        <!-- Page wrapper -->
        <div ng-include="'views/common/topnavbar.html'"></div>

        <!-- Main view  -->
        <div ui-view></div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <div ng-include="'views/common/footer.html'"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- End page wrapper-->

    <!-- Right Sidebar -->
    <div ng-include="'views/common/right_sidebar.html'"></div>

</div>
<!-- End wrapper-->
```

I know I am missing to include the content.html file, but I have no idea how to include with the route provider.

In the past I had the State provider as explained here:
[converting routing from state provider to route provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927292/converting-routing-from-state-provider-to-route-provider)

And it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: only replace `<div ui-view></div>` to `<div ng-view></div>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are using **ui-view** instead of **ng-view**.


Try to use **ng-view** instead of **ui-view**.



If you're going to use **ui-view** inject **ui-router** not **ngRoute**.


**ng-view** and **$routeProvider**  is used when you injected **ngRoute**.

and

**ui-view** and **$stateProvider** is used when you injected **ui.router**



I hope it makes sense.

Comment: that works fine, however the left menu and top menu are not rendered. as in the other question there is a content.html which has the general structure, in state provider there is an attribute called abstract. how can I do that with the ngRoute?

Comment: Can I ask if what is the content of "dashboard_1.html"? "content.html" must be included in the "dashboard_1.html".

Comment: this is a template we bought: https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S, and they used UI Router, However UI Router does not work for us, because we need to inject the ADAL library for authentication, thats why we are trying to remove the uirouter and use ngroute.  the content of dashboard1.html is too long, but here is an screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/RbpJlwUJ2dbd, please give us a recommendation in how should we convert this

Comment: I know the question has been marked as answered, but can you help with the last comment?

Comment: @EstebanV It depends on how complicated the routing is. ui.router has nested and advanced routing compared to ngRoute. So, it depends on how the routing was used.

Comment: The question title is quite generic, leading us landing here ofr any kind of issue causing this blank screen. May this answer be also more generic and provide some information on debugging path ways ?